# Regex if character matches then, else

Tags: regex

I have two regular expressions that work fine to extract text between characters:

1. `(?<=\$)(.*)(?=\*)`
2. `(?<=\$)(.*)(?=)`

For my example text $66* the first expression extracts 66. When the asterisk is not present in the text (i.e. $66), the second expression extracts 66.

How can I combine the two to use the first one if an asterisk is present and the second one if no asterisk is present?

I tried with what I thought would be an if|then|else like below but am doing something wrong: `(?(?=\*)(?<=\$)(.*)(?=\*)|(?<=\$)(.*)(?=))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negated character set to exclude asterisks in your match instead:

```
(?<=\$)[^*]+
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/vuGBiJ/2

Comment: So simple and elegant, thanks for the quick response and fix!

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using a capture group, you could also match the `$` and capture 1+ characters except the  asterix.

```
\$([^*]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w8ke6K/1)